# Is it possible to create a bot for Android using Genymotion on linux?

Tags: android, bots, genymotion

I have genymotion running with all set. I would like to build a script to make some tasks inside an app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your task is similar to automated UI testing. Look at the [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) and [Robotium](http://testdroid.com/tech/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that both Selendroid and Robotium are made to test apps that we are building. I want to make automated tasks for apps available on Google Play Store. I think it's possible to do it with Bluestacks, but I don't want to use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI Automator (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) it's made to inject touch and keyboard events inside the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selendroid or Appium for creating automation scripts for mobile applications. Selendroid is very easy to understand,also you can perform most of the UI related tasks using these Testing Frameworks.

For Selendroid you can follow this link:
http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html

For Appium: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRddxh-4u5k

Hope it will help you. :-)